# I am getting XML junk in the console when trying to connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jdbc, jar

I tried to connect to a MySQL database using Eclipse.

Here's my code:

```java
package Try;

import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource;
import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class SQLtry
{
  public static void runExample()
  {
    Connection connection = null;
    try
    {
      MysqlDataSource ds = new MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource();
      ds.setServerName("localhost");
      ds.setDatabaseName("example");
      connection = ds.getConnection("root", "");
      Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE");
      while(rs.next())
      {
        System.out.println(rs.getInt("num") + "- " + rs.getInt("square"));
      }
      connection.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

At first, everything went fine, and then at some point whenever I try to run it I get some kind of XML file on the console and the program won't run at all (I put a breakpoint on the first line of the program and it never gets there).

What I get is identical to what *abalter* posted in this question:

*[Eclipse giving me XML junk in console instead of running program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626920/eclipse-giving-me-xml-junk-in-console-instead-of-running-program?newreg=1cb3906340114e6e8d13a862063443a3.)*

I tried using both mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar and mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar, and got the same result.

The problem is I can't remove the MySQL JAR files as suggested to him because I need them for the exercise. What can I do?

Comment: Looks like a configuration dump of either the driver or the connection pool formatted as XML.

Comment: So what should I do? Are there other drivers I can use?