# Java mysql - It throws me a xml. A jdk/jre issue?

Tags: java, mysql

Almost the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696773/).

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+server+"/"+bd, user, password);
```

So I get the wonderful and fantastic XML when I run it. I used it before (with another server) and it Works ok.

- My server it's ok because I tested it with another PC.
- I'd say I have update java so I guess there could be the problem, but I have no idea. Could be related with enviroment variables? That specific java version? Btw I have 1.8u45.
- I need mysql.

Comment: That command should look like it does almost nothing, but if it's failing, make sure the mysql connector jar is on your classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I solve it. It wasn't java, nor mysql. It was so easy to see... It was Eclipse:

I have EE Luna version and I don't really know why whenever I clicked run (doesn't matter the Project), it always ran a DocsBlahBlah... file related with mysql ConnectionProperties.

So I deleted that from "Run Config..." and apparently all works fine.

However I'm afraid that will be happening more simply the 1st run config it's the one I need now.